# Casting from a JSON body to a List of a specific Object

Tags: apex, json, rest

I am trying to convert JSON, which is something like this:

```
[{"_id":"55d66226726b611100aaf741","replacement":false,"quantity":5,"name":"Generator 1000 kW","maintenanceperiod":365,"lifespan":120,"cost":5000,"sku":"100003"},{"_id":"55d66226726b611100aaf742","replacement":true,"quantity":183,"name":"Cooling Fan","maintenanceperiod":0,"lifespan":0,"cost":300,"sku":"100004"}...]
```

into a List of Custom object Product2 to then match it by the sku field and then update the Product2 object in salesforce. I tried to convert JSON with the following code:

```
 Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com/equipment');
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
// If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
    List<Product2> results = (List<Product2>) System.JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),List<Product2>.class);
    for(Object a:results){
        System.debug(a);
    }
}
```

However, the debug only shows the Name like so:

```
Product2:{Name=Generator 1000 kW}
```

But is missing all the other fields. What do I need to change for it to have all the fields, not just Name? But the issue is I do not even know how I will match the fields as getting even the name field like a.Name throws me an error "Variable does not exist: Name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON input:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"55d66226726b611100aaf741",
      "replacement":false,
      "quantity":5,
      "name":"Generator 1000 kW",
      "maintenanceperiod":365,
      "lifespan":120,
      "cost":5000,
      "sku":"100003"
   },
   {
      "_id":"55d66226726b611100aaf742",
      "replacement":true,
      "quantity":183,
      "name":"Cooling Fan",
      "maintenanceperiod":0,
      "lifespan":0,
      "cost":300,
      "sku":"100004"
   }"..."
]
```

is a list of objects that aren't `Product2`

The only JSON property that maps to a `Product2` field is `name`

That is why `List<Product2> results = (List<Product2>) System.JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),List<Product2>.class);` only shows names.

You need to deserialize either into a `List<Object>` or into a list of custom ApexTypes. From there you can construct `Product2` objects

Example:

```
Object[] jsonObjects = (Object[]) JSON.deserializeUnTyped(response.body);
for (Object jsonObj : jsonObjects) {
   Map<String,Object> jsonValuesByField = (Map<String,Object>) jsonObj;
   String lifespan =  (String) jsonValuesByField.get('lifespan');
   ...
   // build a Product2

}
```

or, with Apex Types

```
class JsonProduct {
  String _id;
  Boolean replacement;
  Integer quantity;
  ...
}

for (JsonProduct jp : (JsonProduct[]) JSON.deserialize(respopnse.body,List<JsonProduct>.class) ) {
    Product2 p = new Product2(
          Is_Replacement__c = jp.replacement,
          Name = jp.Name,
         ...);
}
```

Comment: But how would I deserialize it into Map<String, Object> if the JSON is a List<Object> type?

Comment: updated my answer